# EditText requestfocus until valid entry

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using the following code. Here what I need is , the `edittext1` should be focused until user makes valid entry and it can pass on next `edittext2` request focus. Where I have mistake here.

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(editext1.getText().toString().length()==2)
            {
                if(Integer.parseInt(editext1.getText().toString()) >= 51)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: It shouldn't be above 50",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editext1.setError("Please Check");
                    editext1.requestFocus();
                }
            }
            else
            return;
            editext2.requestFocus();
     }
```

Here `edittext1` allowed value 0 to 50. If user enter  above 50 it should retain there. If they enter between 0 and 50 then it should be `requestfocus();` on next `edittext1`. But this above code jumped to the next `editext2` even entered above 51

Answer (score 1):

Notice below lines:

```
else
return; //already returned before editext2.requestFocus();comment or delete this line.
editext2.requestFocus();
```

**Edited:**

```
            if(editext1.getText().toString().length()==2)
            {
                if(Integer.parseInt(editext1.getText().toString()) >= 51)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: It shouldn't be above 50",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editext1.setError("Please Check");
                    editext1.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    editext2.requestFocus();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank You. So much... As I  need.

Answer (score 0):

There is  an issue when you call requestFocus().
It should be called as

```
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if (editext1.getText().toString().length() == 2) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(editext1.getText().toString()) <= 50) {
            editext2.requestFocus();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: It shouldn't be above 50", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            editext1.setError("Please Check");
            editext1.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No Still now it skip into next ( edittext2) even entered above 51

Comment: When I enter a single digit it skipped into next.

Comment: Thank You @Syed Sumair . Now it works.. I missed this way.

Comment: There was an issue in my logic for length condition, I've again edited my answer hope it works for your case

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle inner if too. so return from inner if the condition is true

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if(editext1.getText().toString().length()==2)
            {
                if(Integer.parseInt(editext1.getText().toString()) >= 51)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error: It shouldn't be above 50",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    editext1.setError("Please Check");
                    editext1.requestFocus();
                    return; //Add this line only
                }
            }
            else
            return;
            editext2.requestFocus();
     }
```